# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 how to fix it

Tags: android

I'm new I have this error when I connect to server to use data from url to plot graph in android API 4.4.2 . I try to Fix this error but i can't  please tell me how to fix this error

Here this is my code to

```
results = new ArrayList<Result>();
      new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://phm.umr-lab.com/getdata1.php");

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("result");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Day = object.getString("Day");
                        pH = Float.parseFloat(object.getString("pHdata"));
                    }

                    Date.add(Day);
                    ph.add(pH);
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.cancel();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
        private void openChart(){
        int[] x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
        Float[] bar = ph.toArray(new Float[Date.size()]);   
        String[] Datr = Date.toArray(new String[Date.size()]);  
        // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
        //CategorySeries incomeSeries = new CategorySeries("Income");
        XYSeries incomeSeries = new XYSeries("Data");
        // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){            
            incomeSeries.add(i,bar[i]);
        }
        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        // Adding Income Series to the dataset
        dataset.addSeries(incomeSeries);    
        // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
        XYSeriesRenderer incomeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        incomeRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(130, 130, 230));
        incomeRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        incomeRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
        incomeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        multiRenderer.setChartTitle("pHdata");
        multiRenderer.setXTitle("pH 1-14");
        multiRenderer.setYTitle("Date");
        multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);              
        for(int i=0; i< x.length;i++){
            multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Datr[i]);            
        }       
        // Adding incomeRenderer and expenseRenderer to multipleRenderer
        // Note: The order of adding dataseries to dataset and renderers to multipleRenderer
        // should be same
        multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(incomeRenderer);
        // Creating an intent to plot bar chart using dataset and multipleRenderer      
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        // Start Activity
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this is my error

```
    threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x430d4140)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginebarchart, PID: 15991
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginebarchart.MainActivity.openChart(MainActivity.java:164)
    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginebarchart.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:151)
    at in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginebarchart.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:66)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4487)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18746)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @GeorgeThomas there is i < jarray.length() so condition is right additionally the issue occurs in openChat method

Comment: The issue occur in one of these lines   multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Datr[i]);   incomeSeries.add(i,bar[i]);. Check Datr and bar arrays that they have the same or more length as x array

Comment: I will post answer because answer is to long on comment

Comment: Did you try my solution? Does it work? Do you need some explain?

Comment: If my solution was helpful for you and if it resolved your issue - please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues in your code

First is here:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
      Day = object.getString("Day");
      pH = Float.parseFloat(object.getString("pHdata"));
 }
 Date.add(Day);
 ph.add(pH);
```

When you do this in this way as is shown above you always add only the last element from your json. If you want to add all elements from json you have to call `add` method inside of the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
      Date.add(object.getString("Day"));
      ph.add(Float.parseFloat(object.getString("pHdata"));
 }
```

The second issue is in the `openChart()` method. You do this something like below:

```
 int[] x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
 Float[] bar = ph.toArray(new Float[Date.size()]);   
 String[] Datr = Date.toArray(new String[Date.size()]);
 ...  

 for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){            
     incomeSeries.add(i,bar[i]);
 }

 ...
 for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){            
      multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Datr[i])
 }
```

You never check that the x array has the same or greatest length as `bar` and `Datr` arrays - it is very dangerous. You should do something like this:

```
 int[] x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
 Float[] bar = ph.toArray(new Float[Date.size()]);   
 String[] Datr = Date.toArray(new String[Date.size()]);
 ...  
 int firstSize = Math.min(x.length, bar.length);
 for(int i=0;i<firstSize;i++){            
     incomeSeries.add(i,bar[i]);
 }

 ...
 int secondSize = Math.min(x.length, Datr.length);
 for(int i=0;i<secondSize;i++){            
      multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, Datr[i])
 }
```

Now you solution will be safe.